# fitting elements in css3

Tags: css, animation, hyperlink, transform, transition

Two days ago I asked for help with animation css3. 
Here is my animation: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/SD58Z/8/[/link]

Everything works fine, but I have another question. It is possible to set width of this line automatically, that this line fit properly regardless of the length of link text? The point is this line is too short when my title is longer.

I just created a mod and line shows correctly but my animation disappeared.
[link]http://jsfiddle.net/DashDesign/SD58Z/284/[/link]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but this makes the underline span to 500px.

```
.line{
font-family:Tahoma;
width:0px;
position: absolute;


background:black;
transition:width 0.4s ease ;
-moz-transition: 0.4s ease ; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: 0.4s ease ; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: 0.4s ease; /* Opera */
}

div:hover{
width:500px;
}
.line div{
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
    bottom:1px;
}
}
```

2 changes were the width on hover and your fiddle was missing a closing brace at the end

Comment: I try to set the width of the line as "auto". But it does not work. When I change a value of width as auto in div:hover animation does not work.